# CJuiDateTimePicker showing Chinese characters for 'en' language setting

Tags: php, yii, datetimepicker, juice-ui

I toggle language setting ('en' or 'ru') for CJuiDateTimePicker in yii:

```
$this->widget('ext.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'Begin',
        'language'=> substr(Yii::app()->getLanguage(), 0, 2), // Yii::app()->language, 
        // 'options'=>$options, 
        ));
```

but the widget still shows Chinese characters for months in case of English language setting ('en'):[image]

I followed this comment with no avail: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/juidatetimepicker/#c12617
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'language'=> 'en-GB'` as the value for English.

Check out this thread on [the forums](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21661-cjuidatepicker-and-language/)